# PHP Ajax Shell Exec() Progress

Tags: php, ajax, exec, progress

What I'm trying to do is quite simple.

```
echo "doing a...."
Start progress bar
then exec("commandA")
stop progress bar

echo "doing b...."
Start progress bar
then exec("commandA")
stop progress bar

echo "doing c...."
Start progress bar
then exec("commandC")
stop progress bar
```

etc

The progress bar doesn't need to be accurate, more of a comfort to show something is happening.

I've read it can be done using jquery and php/ajax.. but I've no idea how.
Anyone got a simple example I can try a work with ?

Thanks :)

Comment: if you don't know the server side part, tell me to edit my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to use twitter bootstrap:
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#progress

This is the server side part:

```
$command = isset($_GET['command']) ? $_GET['command'] : null;
if ($command == null) {
    die("0");
}
echo (int) exec($command);
```

for ajax you can use jQuery ajax methods like `$.get , $.post , $.ajax`

```
$.get('exec.php', { command: 'commandA'}, function(response) {
    if(response == 1) {
        //and you can easily change the width of the progress bar with jQuery:
        $(".bar").css('width', '40%');
    } else {
        alert("The execution got an error!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not sure how to use this or how to add my exec() calls into it. Sorry :(

Comment: @user1635970 I updated the answer and put the server side example for you. But notice that it may be dangerous and the attacker be able to run harmful commands on your server. If it is your answer, mark it as accepted answer to help to other people

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Not sure how this will work for me as the results I get back from my commands are not going to give me anything of value.. I should have worded my question more around a please wait 'working' image not a progress bar !

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it using `$.get('exec.php', { command: 'ls -l'}, function(response) {` but that returns  "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting T_VARIABLE or '$' in "

Comment: u need to hard code 2>&1 at the end of commad to see full channel output