# Using PHP's exec() function to show wget download progress with Ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, exec

I'm working on a side project that downloads files from ZippyShare.. I've got a fundamental PHP file that works, however I would like to implement a download status indicator with Ajax. Perhaps someone here would be able to help me with that? Here is the wget command template I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21100640/2696690):

```
wget <download_link> \
--referer='<referrer>' \
--cookies=off --header "Cookie: JSESSIONID=<session_id>" \
--user-agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1'
```

So I created a very basic PHP file to demonstrate a working download:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
   $download_link = $_POST['download_link'];
   $download_referer = $_POST['download_referer'];
   $session_id = $_POST['session_id'];
   exec("wget ".$download_link." \ --referer='".$download_referer."' \ --cookies=off --header \"Cookie: JSESSIONID=".$session_id."\" \ --user-agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1'");
} else {
?>

<form method="POST" action="">
    Download Link: <input type="text" id="download_link" name="download_link"><br><br>
    Referrer: <input type="text" id="download_referer" name="download_referer"><br><br>
    Session ID: <input type="text" id="session_id" name="session_id"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Download File">
</form>

<?php
}
?>
```

Now I'm stuck on how to integrate a status indicator on this, I tried doing something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13251516/2696690), but it wasn't much help since I'm looking to have the progress bar dynamically change with the download progress, not set it to a value.

Could anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Uhhhmmmmmmmm. So I can just execute stuff on your server? Does that really sound like a good idea?

Comment: @PeeHaa Well, I wasn't exactly making it public but I did add that to consideration.. Wouldn't it reduce the 'vulnerability' somewhat, if the command is already filled in?

Comment: Yes that would totally not reduce anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (and should) use curl from PHP instead of executing custom commands with exec.

With curl you can listen for the file stream and run a progress function to be run accordingly.

[PHP/cURL download progress monitoring](https://gist.github.com/bdunogier/1030450)

Comment: So with cURL, would I still be able to run the custom arguments similar to the wget command I had in the original question? EDIT: Yep, answered that one myself with curl_setopt(). Thank you!

Comment: Sure. You can pass cURL any parameter you could possibly use, and yet some others.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the help, I've got a clear picture now of how to do it.